# Why is my save/open dialog not popping up?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-3.5, epplus

I have an MVC action method which makes an ajax call to export data to excel, but the open/save dialog is not coming up.  Here is the javascript code:

```
exportExcel = function(el, e, oSettings) {
        Json = self.searchCriteria;
    $.post(url, Json, function(data) {
    }, 'json');
};
```

Here is the Action Method:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(JsonDictionary args)
    {
        var data= GetData();

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            string filename = "Data + ".xlsx";
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(data, true);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            package.SaveAs(stream);

            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            stream.Position = 0;
            return File(stream, contentType, filename);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you can't download files via an ajax call. If you look at this :

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/

this will allow an ajax file download using a dynamic iFrame.